# Using HOOK_username_alter() to hide the real username

Tags: 7, users, hooks

I'm using a pattern for the username creation using the contrib module: [automatic_usernames](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_username), this results in the following pattern for my use case: `[hotel_name][uid]`. Example: Hilton10

Here is the dilemma. This is fine for the business to see, but I do not want them to see their customer's actual username that they just created such as Hilton11 and instead I would like them to see the first name + last name of the customer.

How would I go about this using the following custom fields?

```
[#field_name] => field_customer_first_name

[#field_name] => field_customer_last_name

function MyCustomModule_username_alter(&$name, $account){
 global $user;
    if(in_array('venue admin', $user->roles)) {
    $name = ? //this is where im stuck
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$account` argument in [`hook_username_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_username_alter/7.x) provides the user entity object with all its field values. You can use its field values for your `$name` substitution. For example:

```
function MyCustomModule_username_alter(&$name, $account){
  global $user;

  // This example presumes a field_first_name as a user first name field.
  // It will vary based on your field & language environment.
  // use Devel's dpm() to find your actual value for user entity.
  if (isset($account->field_first_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) 
      && in_array('venue admin', $user->roles)) {
    $name = $account->field_first_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help...since I had two fields that I wanted to concatenate I did the following.

   function MyCustomModule_username_alter(&$name, $account){
       global $user;
           if(isset($account->field_customer_first_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])
        && $account->field_customer_last_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) {
        $name = $account->field_customer_first_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . ' ' . $account->field_customer_last_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
      }
}

Comment: that's not 8.x code, if you are using Drupal 7, you should not use the "8" tag.

Comment: @MRC's original question linked to a 7.x-only module so I'm presuming that was the case. I've changed the tag accordingly.